# How to re-initiate simulation Gazebo & Rviz

Tags: gazebo, simulation, rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a UAV simulation lounched like: `roslaunch cvg_sim_test track.launch`. i'm using Fuerte on ubuntu 12.04.

The position of the drone is set in the launch file. I want to put the drone back to its initial position the position of the drone. How can i do that without restarting the simulation?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/118186/how-to-re-initiate-simulation-gazebo-&-rviz/) by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2014-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Recently i found out that in the Gazego main window Edit menu are the resent commands (**crt + r**). Moreover, the Gazego node has a service `/gazebo/reset_world` does the same.

Thanks curiosity.

---

Originally posted by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) with karma: 231 on 2014-01-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2